# Does react-admin provide login for the customers in the demo site

Tags: react-admin

In the demo site provided, the user demo is the administrator of the site.  There is a list of customers in the demo site, do those customers also have logins to the system to look at their order or invoices?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to source code here: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/examples/demo
As you can see in authProvider.ts there is only one authorized user data and they accept any combination of user/password, so the answer for your question is no.